# Postgres column does not exist but it's there with alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a generated Postgres query

```
select ..., s.name as supplier, ...
from ... supplier s ...
where ...
      AND (cast(supplier as varchar(255)) ilike '%test%')
      ...
ORDER BY supplier desc nulls last
```

I get this error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "supplier" does not exist

if I replace the "supplier" with s.name then it's ok but I can't do that. 
I have this issue on other columns too but there are columns which are working fine.

There are some restriction that I can't use alias the same as the table name or what can be the problem?

Comment: That is correct.  A column alias defined in the `SELECT` cannot be referenced in the `WHERE`.  In Postgres, it can be referenced in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses (and `HAVING`) clauses.

Comment: Any updates for a solution ?:)

Answer (score 22):

I found the explanation here: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/18195.1038530280@sss.pgh.pa.us

I can't use the alias from the select in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: You can create a  Common Table Expressions (with {table_name} as (select ...)) and then use your aliased column inside the query.